# Problemas con los metodos Start y Update en Unity

Tags: unity2d

Tengo este código:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class bullet_codigo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed=1f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector3(0,speed,0);

        if(transform.position.y>10.5)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

No importa si coloco el `if` en la `funcion Start` o `Update` igual me funciona, se supone que el método `Start` se activa solo una vez inicia el programa y el método `Update` es un bucle infinito hasta que termine la ejecución del programa.

¿Por que ejecuta el `if` de la misma manera en el `Update` y en el `Start()`?

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que tu objeto cuando se cree esté en una posición global mayor a 10.5? 
Si al  ejecutar el Start ya esta en esta posicion lo eliminaria. Vigila si se crea dentro de otro objeto, porque si la posicion global Y del padre mas la suya local es mayor a 10.5 te lo destruiria.